# Can I pass an interface to bundle of a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, serialization, interface

Since Fragments need to survive configuration change, it is strongly suggested by Android that we should implement our own `newInstance()` method when creating a fragment, passing necessary data to its `Bundle` instead of using `new MyFragment()`.

Now, the problem is, **I want to pass a callback (interface) to this Fragment**.

At first I tried to make my interface `extends Serializable`, and simply use `args.putSerializable("myInterface", myInterface)`.
But when Android try to save its state (parcel it), an Exception is thrown (Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object).

I know the official way to do this is to make the caller Activity implements the callback, and reference the callback to the activity during `onAttach()` of the fragment.
Yes, it works, but it feels weird, because I am actually creating a library and now instead of asking user to pass a callback to the builder, I have to tell them your caller activity must implements a certain interface.
More importantly, what if I want to show this `Fragment` from another `Fragment`? `onAttach()` always attach to an `Activity`.

So, is there a way that I can let user pass the callback to the fragment, and being able to survive configuration change (e.g. device rotation)?

#### UPDATE

As requested, here is the interface that I want to pass:

```
public interface OnImageSelectedListener extends Serializable {
    void onImageSelected (String uri);
}
```

And how I construct this interface:

```
new OnImageSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSingleImageSelected(String uri) {
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(uri).into(ivImage);
        }
}
```

Comment: Does your Interface uses any Object which doesnot implement Serializable?

Comment: It is just an interface with one method. Ah but the method pass `Uri` as an argument. (`void onSomethingDone(Uri uri);`. Does that matter? (By the way, `Uri` implements `Parcelable`)

Answer (score 1):

At last, I come to the conclusion:

**We should not retain the callback.**

Imagine the callback does the below code:
`Glide.with(context).load(image).into(imageView);`

When device rotates, the above imageView, which belongs to an activity or another fragment, is also destroyed and re-created. **The old `ImageView` that is referenced in the retained  callback no longer exists.**

This will either make Glide throw an exception; or leaks the old `ImageView` and thus the whole `Activity`.

That's why we should always reference the callback to an attaching `Activity`.
And if the caller is a `Fragment`, instead of referencing the callback in `onAttach()`, simply reference the parent fragment in `onCreateView()`:

```
if (getParentFragment() != null && getParentFragment() instanceof YourInterface) {
    yourCallback = (YourInterface) getParentFragment();
}
```

So if to answer the original question,

> Can I pass an interface to bundle of a Fragment?

The answer is, probably no, but you just shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are facing this issue is because,
 `Glide` is non Serializable data and you cannot serialize it. Since serialization is a process defined by Java and done on JVM, it doesn't understand `Parcelable`, hence fails with an error. This is also applicable even if you are just using them in the callback method.

But since you are developing a Library, you won't be able to control the usage of your Callback interface. So the solution would be avoid sending this object by Serializing it.

Instead, when usecase of your library starts (there must be some entry point to tigger the usecase), you need to request your to pass the reference directly to your method. You can then maintain the reference and execute callback when necessary. You need to implement some wrappers to achieve it. And communicate internally through `LocalBroadcastReceiver`

If the above approach is not possible, then only solution would be to ask user of your Library to register for LocalBroadcastReceive and deliver result through Broadcast.

Comment: I think you are wrong. First, I tried what you suggest as replacing `Uri` with `String`, but same Exception was thrown. Second, if I try to extends `Parcelable instead`, when I declare a anonymous callback, I have to implement the necessary method of Parcelable as well. What I mean is, I think this has nothing to do with the arguments passed in the method of the interface. Just like you do not have to concern whether method arguments of a POJO that implements `Serializable`, also implements `Serializable` as well.

Comment: This exception happens only if you are trying to use non-serializable object within the callback. Can you update you question with code that is being sent through callback?

Comment: Even if you create anonymous class and "just pass parameter" compiler still creates the necessary accessor methods whose data needs to be serialized.

Comment: You can check the upated answer

Comment: I later found that this is actually not feasible. What I am trying to do is, restore everything when the dialog fragment is being recreated by the OS. But even if I can save the callback, the activity, views, are all destroyed and recreated, thus different instances. The old callback is of no use. I am now trying to dismiss the DialogFragment before `onSaveInstanceState`, but not yet find a way...

Comment: This is exactly I wanted to say. When the Fragment is destroyed and re-created, your data will be marshalled in byte[] so that it can be saved. This data will be re-used when the view is created again by unmarshalling. since, Glide is not serializable, it won't work.